# Why can I not import sagemaker in python?

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers, amazon-sagemaker

I suddenly started having an import error when trying to import the sagemaker package:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/imputation/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN6google8protobuf15FieldDescriptor12TypeOnceInitEPKS1_'
```

Looking at where the error comes from makes me think it is:

```
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/imputation/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py:47
     45   import binascii
     46   import os
---> 47   from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
     48   _USE_C_DESCRIPTORS = True
     51 class Error(Exception):
```

I usually run other parts of the code, so this import might have been broken a few months back. This part of the code is not tested, and I don't run it frequently. I tried deleting my python environment and doing a clean install of Sagmaker, and it still failed. Here are the packages. It has Python 3.10.8

```
appnope             0.1.3
asttokens           2.2.1
attrs               22.2.0
backcall            0.2.0
boto3               1.26.53
botocore            1.29.53
contextlib2         21.6.0
decorator           5.1.1
dill                0.3.6
executing           1.2.0
google-pasta        0.2.0
importlib-metadata  4.13.0
ipython             8.8.0
jedi                0.18.2
jmespath            1.0.1
matplotlib-inline   0.1.6
multiprocess        0.70.14
numpy               1.24.1
packaging           23.0
pandas              1.5.3
parso               0.8.3
pathos              0.3.0
pexpect             4.8.0
pickleshare         0.7.5
pip                 22.3.1
pox                 0.3.2
ppft                1.7.6.6
prompt-toolkit      3.0.36
protobuf            3.20.3
protobuf3-to-dict   0.1.5
ptyprocess          0.7.0
pure-eval           0.2.2
Pygments            2.14.0
python-dateutil     2.8.2
pytz                2022.7.1
s3transfer          0.6.0
sagemaker           2.129.0
schema              0.7.5
setuptools          66.0.0
six                 1.16.0
smdebug-rulesconfig 1.0.1
stack-data          0.6.2
traitlets           5.8.1
urllib3             1.26.14
wcwidth             0.2.6
wheel               0.38.4
zipp                3.11.0
```

The `protobuf 3.20.3` is probably the problem.
Looking at this: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10571

Answer (score 0):

It was the protobuf version.

`pip install --upgrade protobuf==3.20.1` fixed it.